# Weird behavior trying to pan in 3D Viewport

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Hello I'm recently getting back into Blender after a very long break.

One of the issues I'm facing is weird behavior trying to pan in the Viewport.

When use the following command to pan: Shift key + Middle Mouse Wheel, it will exhibit the expected behavior of paning and not orbiting. However there are times it seems the Shift key is "toggled" and while not holding down shift it will still pan instead of orbiting when I use the middle mouse wheel to orbit. This "toggle" appears to activate seemingly at random. I've included a screenshot that shows in the bottom left that shows options that appear as if I'm holding Shift key, despite not pressing down. I've also tested my shift key to make sure there wasn't a hardware or external error.

My question is: Can I remove the toggle option that appears to happen when pressing Shift? Or is this the intended behavior?[image: Screenshot of my viewport that shows the Shift key is being pressed or toggled despite me not holding the key]